# Why do Chinese Apple Silicon macOS system customers have arm64e ABI enabled by default while USA customers are still on arm64?

Tags: macos, apple-silicon

Recently it came to light that, it appears as though, Apple's Apple Silicon (M1* systems) macOS computers in China generally have the `arm64e` ABI enabled while users of such systems in the USA are still using, by default, the `arm64` ABI.

Does anyone know why this is happening and/or what repercussions there could be from this differential?

Comment: Apple provides info about it here: https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/blob/apple/main/clang/docs/PointerAuthentication.rst
But it's pretty deep.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that @benwiggy, however I'm not seeing any specific logic or indication as to why they're choosing to deploy this first in an Asian-China situation vs in other regions or in smaller test groups. It seems odd and I have yet to find logic that explains or alludes to their decision/thought process.

Comment: *why* Apple does a thing is officially off topic here as only Apple knows why and they are not talking. We focus on solving a a particular issue and leaving the speculation to the pundits.

Comment: Why is a pretty important thing to understand - especially *HERE*. This will, for example, help us to understand whether or not we should or should not do various things such as enabling the ABI and using the ABI now vs later. Is there an imminent release of a non-test since they're doing this? I could greatly extend this and I believe it is very relevant for anyone here.